# SQL Server (Not Express) + Visual Studio Express (vb.net) - Connection possible?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-express

I couldn't find a quick answer on the official pages,
is it possible to write VB projects in the express edition of Visual Studio that connect to a SQL Server that is not the included 'Express' server ?

Any hints appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are no restrictions of that kind on Visual Studio Express, you can connect to any version of SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, but there is some doubt that the wizards in the Express versions of VB would be usable with the non-express versions of Sql Server.  In past versions, the wizards would not work, but you could still do everything in code.

Comment: I've never tried using the database explorer but do use the "configure data source" wizard along with all of the control data-binding editors just fine. I'm going from VB 2008 Express on my machine to SQL 2000 Standard on our server.